# What does ld a,(hl) do in this piece of Z80 ASM code, and why is HL incremented?

Tags: z80

```
ThinkPositive equ 1
PrintChar equ &BB5A

org &8100
    ld hl,Introduction
    call PrintString
    call NewLine
    ld hl,Message
    call PrintString
ret

PrintString:
    ld a,(hl)
    cp 255
    ret z
    inc hl
    call PrintChar
jr PrintString

Introduction:
    db 'Thought of the day...',255

ifdef ThinkPositive
    Message:    db 'Z80 is Awesome!',255
else
    Message:    db '6510 sucks!',255
endif

Newline:
    ld a,13
    call PrintChar
    ld a,10
    call PrintChar
ret
```

For your information, this piece of z80 asm prints 2 strings.

Comment: The code is not very efficient. As already pointed out using `00` as string terminator would make more sense. Using `or a` to test for `00` is only a 1 byte instruction
(note that `ld a,(hl)` when `(hl)` is `00` would *not* set the Z-flag). Furthermore it would make sense to add the `0dh` and `0ah` at the end of the string when a CR/LF needs to be printed instead of adding a subroutine call for it.

Comment: &BB5A - Amstrad CPC?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ld a, (hl)` copies the byte in the address that `hl` points to into register `a`. I assume the printchar routine expects a character byte in this register, probably in ASCII encoding.

Your code loads `hl` with the start address of the string and then iterates through it, printing each character until it reaches 0xFF, when it stops.  The increment moves `hl` to 'point' to the next byte (character).

It's slightly unusual to use 0xFF (255 in decimal) as the end of string marker, but in assembler you can make your own rules!

Comment: _"It's slightly unusual to use 0xFF (255 in decimal) as the end of string marker, but in assembler you can make your own rules!"_ For the Z80 there's no difference, as a test is needed anyway. Then again, considering the shown love got 6500 CPUs, where using Zero would save an instruction, it makes sense to use an encoding where the 6500 can't gain an advantage :)) SCNR

Comment: I was thinking about 'C' style zero-terminated strings. It didn't occur to me that CP 0 might be faster on other processors.

Comment: Here, using zero as the end of string marker would let us use `or a` instead of the `cp 0` that would replace `cp 255`, which saves one byte. `or a` computes the bitwise OR of `a` with itself, which does nothing, but afterwards, the `z` flag is set if `a` is zero.

Comment: @MarkWilliams It's faster, because it isn't needed. When loading a value, Motorola style CPUs set the flags accordingly, so loading Zero will set the Zero flag without any test needed. Same for DEC - you see the picture?